# "Bubbles in the bathtub" novelty song

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics

I heard this song a few times on the radio like Dr. Demento or something.

I sang (my) lyrics to my Mom who is very good with songs but to no avail.

The lyrics are something like:

> Bubbles in the bathtub...
> Going out to sea...
> Bubbles in the bathtub...
> That's where you'll find me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this song doesn't have the lyrics you mentioned, I do remember this bathtub themed diddy played on Dr demento a whole bunch.

Dick Robertson - Singin' In the Bathtub

Comment: Youz got it boss @Bigredboots (or whatever Paul Newman said) Lyrics co-penned by Magdison who co-won the first Oscaro for Best Original Song. Also... your Dick Robertson looks somewhat like Erik Rhodes who sang the latter. Odd version by Gracie Fields, the highest paid movie star in 1937, which sounds like...Bjork?!   j.